# How can I compensate for Chie's weakness to fire attacks?

Tags: persona-4, persona-4-golden

Fighting Yukiko's shadow. Chie is weak against fire attacks. How can I overcome that? I do not know any items or armor which can help at this point of the game.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the Slime Skill "Red Wall" On Chie, to grant her Fire resistance. Its learned by Slime at level 4, and from there you can fuse it onto another more useful persona.

Doing this is a better strategy than having Chie defend because Chie's Mabufu will be a substantial part of your damage dealing ability.